# Highlight cells if their difference is ±2

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns, column A and B, which are pre-filled with numbers.

I want to highlight rows where the differene in numbers is +2 or -2.

So I would need something like:
IF(A1-B1 > 2 or A1-b1 < 2), THEN change text colour.

I am trying to set this up under conditional formatting in Google Sheets.

Comment: Do you mean if the difference is greater than +2 or less than -2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean where the difference is more than 2 either way, shortest would be

```
=abs($A1-$B1)>2
```

as a custom formula.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.